# When deleting a message from an SQS queue, configured with a high value for visibility timeout, if I delete the message, it will be deleted instantly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I tried to find in the documentation but I didn't find anything related.

When deleting a message from an SQS queue, configured with a high value for visibility timeout, should I change the visibility for a less value timeout and delete the message, or can I delete it directly and the message will be deleted instantly?

My fear is if I delete the message without changing the visibility timeout, it will be in flight until the timeout ends and not when the delete operation was called?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the issue, if the message is in flight, it can only be deleted by the node to which it is in flight to, so either way, it is effectively deleted immediately as soon as you call the delete operation.

No other nodes will be able to see it, if that is your concern.

Comment: "it can only be deleted by the node to which it is in flight to", this is not true. It can be deleted by other consumers as long as they have the `ReceiptHandle`

Comment: theoretically yes, but how would a second node get the receipthandle unless the node to whom the message is in flight to, gave it to them? and if node-1 gives it to node-2 (assuming there is ever a valid use-case to do that), the node-1 would/should give up any 'claim' to using it.

Comment: My main concern is about the visibility timeout. Let suppose it is 15 minutes. My node received the message and has processed successfully it in 1 min. After this, it has deleted the message. There is only this message in flight. So, after I call the delete method, the SQS will wait for more than 14 minutes to remove it, or will lt be deleted immediately, and no more messages will be in flight?

Comment: if you delete it, it will be deleted immediately